# H2 performance query

Tags: h2

I'm using an H2 database and the table Matrix has around 500 000 rows. At this time, this query is a little slow.

```
SELECT MAX(b.version) FROM Matrix b WHERE b.state NOT LIKE 'published' AND b.state NOT LIKE 'obsolete'
```

Can I use indexes on column state? They work well if I use LIKE?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read interesting things here: http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html

I suggest to measure run time of your query before and after the change.

And the type of state (which was no included in question) may affect the run time of the query.

Note: If you have few values in state, I suggest to extract the states in a new table and use foreign keys in Matrix. (I suppose it will be faster than textual search)